# change the hours on my date object without transforming it in string

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

So I have this date object

```
const today = new Date()
```

but it's giving me a time with 3 hours ahead of my timezone how do I change it to my TZ without transforming the final result into a string? My database accepts only date objects not strings I have tried with moment() and localeString() but I need it in date object

Comment: This happens because you computer's timezone is messed up. Try changing the timezone of your computer to where you actually are.

Comment: the timezone in my computer is correct

Comment: JavaScript uses the computer's timezone, so it shouldn't return an incorrect time.

Comment: How are you getting the time from `today`?

Comment: Date objects don't have a timezone, they are inherently UTC. Please post example input, expected output and actual output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getHours()` and `setHour()` methods and subtract 3.

```js
const today = new Date();
today.setHours(today.getHours() - 3);
console.log(today.toLocaleString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for [Date.prototype.setHours()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours).

Depending on your use case, implementing it is as simple as:

```js
myDateObject = new Date();
console.log(myDateObject.toLocaleString());

myDateObject.setHours(myDateObject.getHours() - 3);
console.log(myDateObject.toLocaleString());
```